# Android: Best way to communicate with a server

Tags: android, sockets

I created a remote server for an app to connect to using sockets. It connects and receives data just fine when I'm using wi-fi but it rarely receives data when I'm using 3g. Is there a better way of connecting remotely?

Comment: SOAP web services offer protocols for guaranteeing message delivery, but they're really, really expensive compared to a pure socket communication.

Comment: I honestly don't mind if it doesn't always work but the problem is I've only got it to work once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I understand is that you may be transferring a large amount of data over sockets.

So, when you are on a faster connection, it goes through quickly, but when you are on a slower 3G connection, it takes a long time to go through.

So, if possible try to reduce the amount of data which gets transferred.

You can also try  some mechanism like
http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/zip/GZIPOutputStream.html
There is a corresponding http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/zip/GZIPInputStream.html .

These streams compress the data to send it over the socket and decompress on the receiving side. So, it increases your processing time a little bit but reduces the amount of data being transmitted.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear. Do you mean you created a server app on Android?  If so, I'm guessing the problem is the server address is probably reachable over a local wifi but not over 3G.

Comment: No I created a server application on my computer. The server is definitely reachable over 3g since I've been able to connect with the web server piece of it over 3g. Sorry if I'm not understandable I'm still trying to get a grasp on the jargon.